# unhandled exception type error

Tags: java, android, unhandled-exception

I have never gotten this error before so I am not sure what to do or what it means

> Unhandled exception type `OperationApplicationException`

It occurs in this code:

```
public void putSettings(SharedPreferences pref){
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
          new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(pref.getString(SmsPrefs.ID, ""))})
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,"vnd.android.cursor.item/color")
    .withValue("data1",nColor).build());
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops); //error


    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(pref.getString(SmsPrefs.ID, ""))})
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE,"vnd.android.cursor.item/vibrate")
    .withValue("data1", nVibrate).build());
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops); //error

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(pref.getString(SmsPrefs.ID, ""))})
    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/sound")
    .withValue("data1", ringTonePath).build());
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);//error
}
```

It gives me 2 options "add throws declaration" and "surround with try/catch".

What do I have to do and why?

Comment: What line does this is thrown on? You are violating the constraints on contact operation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It means a method you're calling is declared with the `throws` directive for an exception derived from the `Exception` class.  When a method is declared in this way, you are forced to deal with the exception using a `try/catch` block or add an identical `throws` (for the same exception or a super type) statement to your method declaration.

An example.

I want to call some method `foo` inside my method `bar`.

Here is `foo`'s definition:

```
public static void foo(String a) throws Exception {
    // foo does something interesting here.
}
```

I want to call `foo`.  If I simply do this:

```
private void bar() {
    foo("test");
}
```

...then I'll get the error you are experiencing.  `foo` declares to the world that it really might decide to throw an `Exception` and you had better be ready to deal with it.

I have two options.  I can change `bar`'s definition as follows:

```
private void bar() throws Exception {
    foo("test");
}
```

Now I've publicized my own warning that my method or some method I call could throw an `Exception` that the user of my method should deal with.  Since I've deferred responsibility to my method's caller, my method doesn't have to deal with the exception itself.

It's often better to deal with the exception yourself, if you can.  That brings us to the second option, the `try/catch`:

```
private void bar() {
    try {
        foo("test");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.wtf("MyApp", "Something went wrong with foo!", e);
    }
}
```

Now I've dealt with the potential `Exception` thrown by `foo` that the compiler was complaining about.  Since it's been dealt with, I don't need to add a `throws` directive to my `bar` method.